# Batch "set /p" returns blank

Tags: batch-file

So I have a "set /p" line in my batch code, but no matter what I seem to do it always returns blank.

My code:

```
@echo off

IF NOT "%1" == "admin" (
    ECHO 'Not admin'
    Pushd "%~dp0"
    copy %0 C:\

    runas /user:administrator "C:\%~n0.bat admin %COMPUTERNAME%"
)

IF "%1" == "admin" (

    set /p user= User initials: 

    ECHO Test: %user%

    wmic computersystem where caption='%2' call rename 'GLOS-%user%01'
    net localgroup administratorer %user% /add
    manage-bde -off C:
    pause
    start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
)
pause
```

Anyone having any clue as to why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One observation I'd like to make, if the user doesn't have administrative privileges, they will be unlikely to have the necessary permissions to copy to the root of the system drive which is a protected area.

Comment: That isn't a problem for what I'm using it for, it copies fine and starts the new bat file, it even deletes it after.

The issue is that the Local Admin doesn't have access to the drive the bat file is on, and we don't want to having to copy paste it for each PC we have to install :)

Comment: You then need to get rid of two lines, `IF "%1" == "admin" (` and the second last line `)`.

Comment: Why do I need to get rid of those? They are just used to check if the bat file is started from the file itself.. or is the issue that you can't "set /p" inside an if statement in batch? o.O

Comment: You are setting a varaible, %user% inside an if block. Normally for this you'd need to enable delayed expansion and use the format !user!. In this case howerver there is no need for that if block because you've already ensured that admin is given as a parameter prior to that point.

Comment: If you really want to keep that IF block then you need to use delayed expansion.  Which means you need to add this line to your code: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then you need to reference your variables with exclamation points instead of percent symbols: `!user!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this at the beginning of your script (e.g. right below `@eho off`):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and further you have to surround user with !...! instead of %...%:

```
ECHO Test: !user!
```

That's it. For more information check [this website](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: This did the trick thanks! :)

But I did go with @Compo 's suggestion of just removing the second if statement, but as I can't accept his comment as the answer, I will accept this as it worked aswell.